# Prevent UIButton.imageView from resizing by image

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimageview, uiimage, size

I have a `UIButton` with a fixed height of 40 (constraint height of 40) where I set an image via code thats an pdf (vectorgraphic) of size **64x64**.
The result should be:

[image]

I have added the image like the following:

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-clear"];
[self setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The result I'm getting is:

[image]

Added a black border to the `imageView` for better visualisation. The `imageView` has a final size of **64x40**.

The thing that happen, I guess, is that the `imageView` gets the image and will be resized to **64x64** and downsized by button constraints to 40 again but reserves the width of 64.

I tried multiple things:

```
self.imageView.frame = CGRect(0,0,32,32);
self.imageView.bounds = CGRect(0,0,32,32);
```

or

```
let aspectRatioConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
[self.imageView addConstraint:aspectRatioConstraint];
```

or

```
[self.imageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:32];
```

The only thing that made a visual change was:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but ended up in bad imagequality and I guess high performance issues.

I just want to use the pdf vector file on multiple size situations. How can I give the buttons imageView a fixed size with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` for the image.

thx a lot!

Comment: BTN.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Comment: It is of course, the problem are the size of the imageView that stays at 64, so I have this distances to the title and the left edge of button.

Comment: you haven't provided the constraint for width. That's why it is taking the internal size of image

Comment: Yeah how can I do that? Doing it by code have no effect as you can see, tried It on two ways. And UIButton has no storyboard or something where I can set it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by adding `self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(4, 4, 32, 32);` to the `- (void)layoutSubviews {}` method.

So

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(4, 4, 32, 32);
}
```

have done it.